# Second largest value in a group

Tags: sql, group-by

I want to select second largest value in each group, how can I do that in SQL?

For example with the below table,

```
IDs value
ID1 2
ID1 3
ID1 4
ID2 1
ID2 2
ID2 5
```

When grouping by IDs, I want this output

```
IDs value
ID1 3
ID2 2
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what we need. You can edit your question with details of the exact problem you are having, what you have tried to solve it and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by value desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate way - you can use dense_rank().

It will make sure that your SQL always returns second largest value even when you have two records with largest value.

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, dense_rank() over (partition by id order by value desc) as rrank
      from t
     ) t
where rrank = 2;
```